# How to find distinct records in JPA where id(Primary key) is different

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have below records in postgres table,
id:1, name:'ABC', tech:'Java'
id:2, name:'DEF', tech:'DotNet'
id:3, name:'ABC', tech:'Java'

when I am running findByName or findDistinctbyName , it is giving all 3 records. but my requirement is to get record 1 and 2.
AnyOoe please suggest JPa query to retrieve expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to resolve duplicated by retaining the earliest `id`, you could use the following `GROUP BY` query:

```sql
SELECT MIN(id) AS id, name, tech
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name, tech;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your response , yes we can acheive it using native query but Is there JPA query which returns expected response

Comment: My query should also basically run as JPQL...have you tried doing that?

Comment: yes , working as JPQL , Thanks